Godot collision issue
So, I'm making a slime game in Godot 4.2, and the issue is that the soft body is falling through the floor like a water droplet. You may edit it.
Here's the project. (Yes, I did intercept the requests to manually delay the download.) Also, I suspect something like the pos is going negative.
